# Simple rectangle box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do put rectangular box around few controls on my winform? (i dont want the grouping thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your controls into a panel and set its `BorderStyle` from `None` to `FixedSingle` - it is the easiest way

Comment: I guess I will take your answer as I am looking for simplest way to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx), you can put your controls in a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) and set its [BorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.borderstyle.aspx) property to `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` or `BorderStyle.Fixed3D`.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the [`GroupBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)? Grouping together a related set of controls is *exactly* what it's intended for. Your users have seen it in every other application they use, and throughout the Windows shell. They're much more likely to recognize what it means than your own custom-drawn rectangle. Deviating from standard platform conventions is rarely a good idea. I *strongly* recommend using the `GroupBox` control, even if it's not exactly the perfect look that you had in mind.

That being said, it's certainly possible to draw your own box around a group of controls on a form. To do so, you'll need to override your form's `OnPaint` method and write some code to draw a rectangle. Doing it this way gives you complete control over the color of your box, as well as the line thickness.

```
protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Call the base class
    base.OnPaint(e);

    // Create your drawing pen
    using (Pen p = new Pen(SystemColors.WindowText, 2.0))
    {
        // Calculate the position and dimensions of the box
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);

        // Draw the rectangle
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
    }
}
```

The only thing you'll need to add is the code that calculates the dimensions of your rectangle, relative to the controls you want it to surround. Use the [`Location` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) of each control to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyh3c8h8.aspx

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 20, 10, 300, 100);
```

You can draw lines on a windows form this way. This would hook into the Paint method where e is PaintEventArgs

Comment: You forgot to dispose the `Pen` object you created. This code leaks resources, a real problem if you're executing it over and over each time the form receives a `Paint` event. Wrapping the object creation in a `using` statement is the best way to do that.

Comment: Yeah - literally just copied that from the link. The link points out that disposal is necessary.